# Remove comma after span with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a comma that exists after a span with a class, like so:

```
<p>Red, green, <span class="no-comma">I don't wanna the next comma</span>, blue, yellow.</p>
```

So far I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var noCommas = jQuery('.no-comma').nextAll();
        noCommas = noCommas.replace(/,/g, '');
    });
</script>
```

...with no success.

Comment: So, where would `str` be coming from?

Comment: aaah good, it should be "noCommas" right? Will amend that on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `nextAll()` for this is it only collects sibling *elements*, but not text nodes.

The only jQuery method that can collect text nodes along with elements is `contents()`

You can use the underlying native `element.nextSibling` and see if it is a text node and starts with a comma as follows:

```js
$('.no-comma').each(function() {
  const next = this.nextSibling;
  if ( next && next.nodeType === 3 && next.textContent.startsWith(',') ) {
    // String#replace() only acts on first instance
    next.textContent = next.textContent.replace(',', '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Red, green, <span class="no-comma">I don't wanna the next comma</span>, blue, yellow.</p>
```